# Spring-data-elasticsearch maven dependency not found

Tags: java, spring, maven, pom.xml, spring-data

I clone repository from `https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/master/pom.xml`

In pom.xml I have:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.M2</version>
</dependency>
```

but maven can not find this lib in repository.
I also try: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch
but it is the same spring-data-elasticsearch version.

Comment: Can you try to change the version to 1.0.0.M1. This is working for us.

Comment: 1.0.0.M1 is old version. There are lot of new feature set added in newer version including elasticsearch version upgrade etc. highly recommended to use current version which is RC1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using Maven Central as your repository. I didn't see it [there](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Corg.springframework.data) either.

According to the [project site](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch#maven-configuration), `spring-data-elasticsearch` is available at http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone. Did you try this repo?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following **repository**.

```
<repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>spring-snapshot</id>
                <name>Spring Maven SNAPSHOT Repository</name>
                <url>http://repo.springsource.org/libs-snapshot</url>
            </repository>
</repositories>
```

**Dependency**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0.M1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I try once again after few hours and It works. Seriously I have no idea why. Correct configuration is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.RC1</version>
</dependency>

<repository>
  <id>spring-libs-milestone</id>
  <name>Spring Milestone Repository</name>
  <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
</repository>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not understanding where is the confusion here ?

Project is not yet fully released hence it's still using milestone repo of springsource instead of maven central repo. It will get released within 2 weeks with Spring Data release train Dijkstra.

[Spring Data Elasticsearch GitHub page](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch) stats that

Maven configuration

Add the Maven dependency:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.RC1</version>
  </dependency>

  <repository>
    <id>spring-libs-milestone</id>
    <name>Spring Milestone Repository</name>
    <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
  </repository>
```

If you'd rather like the latest snapshots of the upcoming major version, use our Maven snapshot repository and declare the appropriate dependency version.

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
 </dependency>

 <repository>
   <id>spring-libs-snapshot</id>
   <name>Spring Snapshot Repository</name>
   <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
 </repository>
```